# finding list element in list that contains dictionary by key

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, indexing

```
{ 'id1': [{'id2': [messageobject, messageobject1]}, {}], 'next_id': [{'example_key': messageobj},{'example_key2': messageobj}]
```

how do i find the list index by search of the key"id2" in list id1
The index of the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided dictionary does not work as is, but this is how you will get the index:

```
for i, dict_ in enumerate(d.get('id1')):
  if 'id2' in dict_:
    print("Fount at index: " + str(i))
```